# AS3 FacebookDesktop Login fail with OAuthException - #2500 An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api, air

I think this is because Facebook just made some changes to their login process.

A few days ago, my air app was working with the FacebookDesktop class from the [facebook-actionscript-api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/). Today I opened the project, and noticed that the Facebook login screens are a little different than when I started building my app. After I type my userID and password in, I grant the app access to my public profile, friend list and photos. Then another screen comes up where I grant the app permission to post to my friends on my behalf.

Then the window closes, and I get 'OAuthException 2500 An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.'

When I sign into Facebook through a browser, I see that my app shows up under "Your Apps" but I can't log in and do anything through my app.

I'm using Adobe Flash with GraphAPI_Desktop_1_8_1.swc on OSX Lion.

Here is my code:

```
public function MyApp(){
     FacebookDesktop.init(APP_ID, onInit);
}
protected function onInit(result:Object, fail:Object):void {
    if (result) {
        trace("onInit, Logged In\n");
    } else {
        trace("onInit, Not Logged In\n");
        var permissions:Array = ["publish_stream", "user_photos"];
        FacebookDesktop.login(onLogin, permissions);            
    }
}
protected function onLogin(result:Object, fail:Object):void {
    if (result) { 
        trace("Logged In as:");
        trace(FacebookDesktop.getSession().user.name);
    } else {        
        trace("Login Failed");  
        trace('code: '+fail.error.code); //code: 2500
        trace('message: '+fail.error.message); //message: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
        trace('type: '+fail.error.type); //type: OAuthException
    }
}
```

I get the same results when I use the FlashDesktopExample provided in the SDK (modified with my app ID of course).

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. I'm not Vijay, but I can pretend to be if it gets me a solution faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem:
The LoginWindow class sets the token based on the uri.

This worked fine until the LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL (`http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`) and the LOGIN_SUCCESS_SECUREURL (`https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`) pages stopped including the access token in the uri.

Hence, the token is never set. Even though my app shows up under the 'Your Apps' section in Facebook after I login, my app still can't do anything without a token.

I have two solutions:

The easiest is to change the LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL and/or the LOGIN_SUCCESS_SECUREURL properties in com.facebook.graph.core.FacebookURLDefaults like the following.

beginning on line 82:

```
public static var LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL:String = 'http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html';
public static var LOGIN_SUCCESS_SECUREURL:String = 'https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html';
```

Change to:

```
public static var LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL:String = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/';
public static var LOGIN_SUCCESS_SECUREURL:String = 'https://www.yoursecurewebsite.com/';
```

of course you would use your own website - not '`http://www.yourwebsite.com/`'. I tried it using `http://localhost/` and it worked great.

Another solution is:

Change com.facebook.graph.windows.LoginWindow with the following code. I have made some changes to my files, so please forgive me if the line numbers are different than what they are in a fresh copy of the SDK.

around line 143:
change:

```
vars.redirect_uri = FacebookURLDefaults.LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL;
```

to:

```
vars.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/';
```

In production code, you probably want to use your own website address instead of `localhost`, but I used localhost for testing purposes.

Then, in the handleLocationChange function (should be around line 168) add this to the else if statements:

```
}else if (html.location.indexOf ('http://localhost/') == 0) {               
    loginCallback(getURLVariables(), null);
    userClosedWindow = false;
    html.stage.nativeWindow.close();
    html.removeEventListener(Event.LOCATION_CHANGE, handleLocationChange);
}
```

As I said before, change localhost to your website address.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, you are right about the cause of the problem, the succes url does not contain any parameters, I tried all your solutions but even if the redirect url is changed to my application redirect url after a successfull login I stil get a plain url with no params, do you know other way to get the access token?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem, too: the success URL did not have any parameters.

Cadderly82 is correct; it's a problem with secure navigation. Turning off my Facebook account's "Secure Browsing" option fixed the problem, but I didn't want to have to require users to do that.

I was able to solve this by setting ALL of the FacebookURLDefaults values to use "https://".

Now I get a valid user-access-token in the success URL; and I get valid values regardless of my facebook account's secure-browsing setting.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem for random users and I don't really know if it is a Facebook problem with secure navigation:

Check user properties in Facebook: Security Settings > Secure Browsing
(www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security)

- For users with "disabled" state it works fine.
- For users with "migration" state it gives the error.
- For users with previously "enabled" state it works fine.

When I tried with users in "migration" state and changed to "disabled", it worked fine. 
Then if I turned it "enabled", the "migration" state is gone and marked as "enabled", but the error it's still there.
So I guess this is the problem, but don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

alot has change in a year this is what i think the answer is now
you need a token to login FacebookDesktop.getSession().accessToken

```
public function MyApp(){FacebookDesktop.init(APP_ID, onInit, FacebookDesktop.getSession().accessToken); }
```